# How to set spawn in the Nether

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I set a (world)-spawn in the nether, so that when a player dies, they respawn in the nether? I am unwilling to use the trick of moving the nether to the overworld. A respawn anchor is nice, but I want them to keep working even after a few deaths. I also don't want to make glowstone accessible to the player (before reaching the overworld).

The player starts in the nether, and the respawn should work similarly to the world spawn. The player should not be able to 'cheat respawn' their way to the overworld without going there first and setting a bed as spawn.

My idea was to set up a respawn anchor in the nether, and a repeating command block which keeps replacing the respawn anchor with a full one in the overworld spawn chunks. Only this doesn't work for new players.

Comment: You can use the `/spawnpoint` command rather than messing around with respawn anchors. But that probably still won't work for new players.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like it's supported in vanilla java. If you're running the server yourself you could use a mod like [GlobalSpawn](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/globalspawn). The other alternative is quite funny: set up tripwires in the overworld spawn that trigger commandblocks that teleports them to the nether spawn (have not tested if this is possible).

Comment: You can set the spawn point in the Nether using the "setworldspawn" command.

Comment: @artista_sin_nombre according to the [wiki](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Commands/setworldspawn), you cannot: "This command can not be used to set the world spawn in any dimension other than the Overworld. In Java Edition, if executed in another dimension, the command will act as if it succeeded, but the world spawn will not be changed."

Answer (score 2):

For new players in repeating command block:
`execute as @a[tag=!joined] in minecraft:the_nether run tp @s x y z`

In a conditional chain command block:

`execute in minecraft:the_nether spawnpoint @a[tag=!joined] x y z`

In a conditional chain command block:

`execute as @a[tag=!Joined] run tag @s add joined`

this would be more efficent in a datapack but it can still work with just commands

edit: i changed it to allow players to overwrite there spawnpoint that is in the nether

Comment: except that will overwrite players spawn to always be at x y z, even if they make a respawn anchor.